# Does a simulacrum'd creature's statblock include its personality and knowledge/memories?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, alignment, simulacrum

Basis: In the *clone* spell, it states clearly that

> The clone is physically identical to the original and has the **same personality, memories,** and abilities, but none of the original’s equipment.

while *simulacrum* does not have this text. *Simulacrum* does state, however, that

> Otherwise, the illusion uses all the **statistics** of the creature it duplicates, except that it is a construct.

The 5e SRD definition of "statistics" also refers to that as its "stat block", which consists of features like its type, race, ability scores, features, and notably, **its alignment.** And according to the suggested post ([What all is included in a creature's game statistics?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138783/what-all-is-included-in-a-creatures-game-statistics)), it only makes mention of alignment without addressing personality or memories and does not provide me with a satisfactorily specific answer.

By the language of *clone* and *true polymorph* as examples, does a sim'd creature's statblock include its current knowledge/memories and personality?

Comment: The suggested post does not provide me with a satisfactory answer. The closest approximation I can find is that it lists "alignment" as being part of a creature's statblock. However, that does not answer if personality and memories are transferred if a simulacrum is created from an already-existing creature; nor does it answer another point, if alignment is synonymous with personality.

Comment: Also related: [How do simulacra behave?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106731/how-do-simulacra-behave), [What does a Simulacrum know?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106744/what-does-a-simulacrum-know)

Comment: Is your question covered by either/both of those two?

Comment: Yes and no, puzzlingly enough. They contradict each other.

The Know question's top answer states that simulacra cannot imitate the target convincingly, which means that they lack the knowledge and personality of the target: a body with no brain, so to speak.
The Behave question's top answer states that "if the creature you copied was fiercely independent and highly intelligent . . . and you told it to 'act natural', it would do so," which implies that its personality and at least some memories transfer over.

I'm starting to think this one may be just up to complete interpretation.

Comment: However, the Behave question is more angled towards just that: the behavior of the sim'd creature, rather than what its mental retention actually is.